# Get top 10 values in hash map

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I am trying to figure out how could I get the top 10 values from the `HashMap`. I was initially trying to use the `TreeMap` and have it sort by value and then take the first 10 values however it seems that that is not the option, as `TreeMap` sorts by key.

I want to still be able to know which keys have the highest values, the `K, V` of the map are `String, Integer`.

Comment: what do you mean the top 10 ? based on what?

Comment: Can you please post some code to show what kind of elements you are comparing?

Comment: TreeMap can do the sorting for you. But in order for us to know what you are trying to sort it by u have to tell us!

Comment: Ahh sorry missed it out, the K,V are String,Integer. I still need to know which keys have the highest values.I have tried TreeMap but it only sorts by key as defined in the specification.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should implement the `Comparable` Interface to your value objects stored in the hashmap.
Then you can create a array list of all values:

```
List<YourValueType> l = new ArrayList<YourValueType>(hashmap.values());
Collection.sort(l);
l = l.subList(0,10);
```

Regards

Comment: Quite good solution. I just needed something similar. Since you are only providing values, but I also needed the keys. I made a slight modification and added a Comparator in order to use the entry set. The comparator has to compare the entry values in descending order.

List<Entry<String,Integer>> results = new ArrayList<>(hashmap.entrySet());

Collections.sort(results, new EntryComparator());
results = results.subList(0, 10);

Comment: I am adding it as another answer because it looks bad as a comment

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<String,Double> map = new HashMap<String,Double>();
        ValueComparator bvc =  new ValueComparator(map);
        TreeMap<String,Double> sorted_map = new TreeMap<String,Double>(bvc);

        map.put("A",99.5);
        map.put("B",67.4);
        map.put("C",67.4);
        map.put("D",67.3);

        System.out.println("unsorted map: "+map);

        sorted_map.putAll(map);

        System.out.println("results: "+sorted_map);
    }
}

class ValueComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    Map<String, Double> base;
    public ValueComparator(Map<String, Double> base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    // Note: this comparator imposes orderings that are inconsistent with equals.    
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        if (base.get(a) >= base.get(b)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        } // returning 0 would merge keys
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, I think that might just do it, going to give it a shot now,THANKS!

Comment: @Biswajit, can you explain me the complexity of this code? Your code is working perfectly and its very easy approach, just wanted to calculate the complexity of this code....

Comment: @Biswajit, you code is great, but how do you ensure the size of TreeMap is 10 at all times? Because you only want to TOP TEN right? 
Everytime you insert a key-value pair into the Tree Map, you need to check if the current size is greater than ten, if it is, you need to delete the smallest key-value pair in the TreeMap. How do you do this last part in the code? I didn't think people would answer my question here, so I asked a new question referencing this post [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37244198/how-to-maintain-a-java-treemap-size-to-be-a-constant-while-adding-key-value-pair)

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you'll have to iterate over the entire map. [Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) is a commonly-used data structure for finding top K elements, as explained in [this book](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hyvdUQUmf2UC&pg=PA392).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the 10 highest values of the map (assuming the values are numeric or at least implementing Comparable) then try this:

```
List list = new ArrayList(hashMap.values());
Collections.sort(list);
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
   // Deal with your value
}
```

Comment: This will only work if the value type `Foo` implements `Comparable<Foo>` and you don't use the raw type of list.

Comment: I would have put the raw type if the OP specified it in his question :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a Map, but this example can work for any type of

```
Map<String, String> m = yourMethodToGetYourMap();
List<String> c = new ArrayList<String>(m.values());
Collections.sort(c);
for(int i=0 ; i< 10; ++i) {
    System.out.println(i + " rank is " + c.get(i)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I base my answer in this one from [sk2212](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436516/get-top-10-values-in-hash-map/15436724#15436724)

First you need to implement a descending comparator:

```
class EntryComparator implements Comparator<Entry<String,Integer>> {

    /**
     * Implements descending order.
     */
    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> o1, Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
        if (o1.getValue() < o2.getValue()) {
            return 1;
        } else if (o1.getValue() > o2.getValue()) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Then you can use it in a method such as this one for the attribute "hashmap":

```
public List<Entry<String,Integer>> getTopKeysWithOccurences(int top) {
    List<Entry<String,Integer>> results = new ArrayList<>(hashmap.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(results, new EntryComparator());
    return results.subList(0, top);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        // Initialize map
        System.out.println(getTopKeysWithOccurences(map, 10));
}

public static List<Entry<String,Integer>> getTopKeysWithOccurences(Map mp, int top) {
        List<Entry<String,Double>> results = new ArrayList<>(mp.entrySet());
        Collections.sort(results, (e1,e2) -> e2.getValue() - e1.getValue());
        //Ascending order - e1.getValue() - e2.getValue()
        //Descending order - e2.getValue() - e1.getValue()
        return results.subList(0, top);
}
```