# How to maintain a Java TreeMap size to be a constant while adding key-value pairs into the TreeMap?

Tags: java, treemap, max-heap

[CODE IS HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15436822/4508172) is a nice and simple example of TreeMap in java to keep track of the key-value pairs added to the map in a sorted order. However, I am unsure on how to ensure that I only keep 10 items in the TreeMap. How to ensure that the size of the TreeMap is always a constant, like 10? So the original problem is: to keep track of the top ten key-value pairs weighted by value in the TreeMap while the stream of key-value keeps coming in.

I want to see how the to write the code in java to constrict the size of the TreeMap. I'm thinking it is something like this:
first add the new key-value pair into the TreeMap, then you check the size of the TreeMap, if it is greater than 10, then delete the smallest key-value pair from the TreeMap and the size returns back to 10 and the TreeMap is ready to add a new key-value pair inside of it.

Comment: You have an idea on how to solve the problem. Have you tried implementing it? If so, what are the problems you encountered? Show us some code.

Comment: I see you have an idea, there is only one extra step to make to have an implementation of it : do it.

Comment: You may not need a map if you only keep 10 elements.